# Problems while trying to move files from HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Recently I bought a new SSD to replace a 1 TB HDD with Windows 10 installed. After getting the SSD, my next step was to install windows 10 on it. After installing Windows on the SSD I basically had 2 bootable drives, on the HDD and SSD.

After booting from the HDD I moved all the files I wanted from the HDD to the SSD because I didn't back up to the cloud. Everything was working properly, but when I finally booted from the SSD and was trying to see the files I moved, I got an error of "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable". Additionally, some files/folders had disappeared and my SSD was still showing used space because of them. Is there a way to recover my files?

Comment: Did one or the other Windows have fast start up on? That sets hibernation flag and restores file structure when coming out of hibernation. But then anything done by some other system is lost. Regular problem with dual booting Linux but applies to any dual boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I think both had fast start up on. I'm gonna try those solutions, thank you!

Comment: Whatever happened, the lesson is: in such cases do not move data; *copy* it, use the new drive and see if everything is fine. Several days (weeks?) later, when you know the hardware and the data is fine, remove the original data if you think you don't need it anymore.